# Embedding quotation marks in command string generated by AWK?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I need to match all instances of strings in one file, with a master list in another.  However, if my string is `abc` I want only that, not `abcdef`, `abc1234` and so on.

So, a word boundary for the regex?  Right now, I'm using a simple awk one liner:

```
cat results_file| sort -k 1| awk -F" " '{ print $1" /home/owner/file_2_search"}'|
xargs -L 1 /bin/grep -i
```

However, to force a word boundary, I'd need to grep `string\b` and the quotes (single or double) seem to be required.

In awk, `\b` is a special character, you need `\\b` ... And the quoted quotes ... (arg) ... Or am I missing something and overdoing this?

This is a Linux box, so presumably gawk.  I have gone over quoting rules for awk, and realize this has got to be simple (and not complex ... but), but am not seeing it.

Comment: [edit] your question using the editor's `{}` button to format all code, sample input, and expected output properly so it's readable.

Comment: Sure (this will probably be a mess, but it makes sense)    abc
abcd
jk1234
oo_123
xyz
xyzabc

Comment: I dont understand what your script is doing or what that stuff about double escaping \b and quoting quotes is about. Also you say you want to match on strings but then you're discussing regexps - which do you want to match on? Please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates what you are trying to do and which we could test a potential solution against.

Comment: cannot get a table to display properly.  Suspect the issue is a quote, not a regexp as such, but the two are intertwined.  Will try again later, and close this.

Answer (score 0):

Had meant to post as an answer, not a comment.  Will try to pose a more readable question, but confess to having second thoughts about doing this as a one-liner in the first place -- may be best to follow an alternate method.  Appreciate the willingness to help.
--Joe